# Cannot get check box to alert("...") when it is contained in a ContentPane

Tags: javascript, jquery

My check box will alert when it is by itself but when I contain it in a title pane then content pane nothing happens:

```
    <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="padding: 0;">

        <div style="position: absolute; left: 2px; bottom: 2px; z-Index: 999;">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title:'Options', closable:false, open:true">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="width: 230px; height: 275px; overflow: auto;">

                     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check"  />
                    <input type="submit" name="email_submit" value="submit" onclick="validate()/>

              </div>    
          </div>
        </div>              
    </div>

<script>
        function validate(){
              var remember = document.getElementById('army');
              if (remember.checked){
                alert("checked") ;
              }else{
                alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
              }
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the `id` attribute on `<input type="checkbox">`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="army" name="checkbox" value="check"  />
```

and also close the attributes:

```
onclick="validate()"/>
//-----------------^
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delay